# Posting on facebook wall with offline permission without browser

Tags: java, php, facebook, servlets

I'm developing a facebook application that post on the user wall with offline permission guaranteed. I'm using PHP with the facebook api (this code is in "index.php"):

```php
$user = $_GET['user'];
(if(isset($_GET['publish'])) {
    $attachment = array(
                    'message' => "My message", 
                    'link'    => "http://...",
                    'picture' => 'my_url_picture',
                    'name'    => "link_name",
                    'caption' => 'my_caption',
                    'description'=> 'my_description'
                    );
    $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', $attachment);
}
```

Now, I use a Java servlet that, when an event occurs, has to post on the user wall in this way:

```java
if(event) {
  Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
  String url_post = "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/index.php?publish=1&user=user_id";
  rt.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url_post);
}
```

All is ok. When the event occurs my server open the browser at the previous link and the post appears correctly on the user (with user_id) wall.
Is possible to "visit" the link without open a browser page? I'm using resin 4.0 for testing my app, Windows 7 Pro Service Pack 1 (but tested also in Windows XP).
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

if i've understood you right, you don't know how to post without opening system browser. Maybe you should look for programming browser like Snoopy (http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/). You can make http requst without opening anything.

Comment: Yes, you have understood me, but I read here that Snoopy is a PHP class. The problem is not PHP because if I visit my index.php page the code works fine. The problem is java side, beacuse I have to visit my page with my servlet. If I use Snoopy I can only simulate a browser, but for do this I've to access on index.php, so we are at the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the apache httpclient project.

Comment: From the official site: The Commons HttpClient project is now end of life, and is no longer being developed.